# Conditionally executing controller callbacks based on values from params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, callback

I am trying to create two callbacks that will be executed dynamically based on a boolean value found in the params hash. How do I implement an If/Else clause to run different callbacks? Do callbacks even have the ability to access data within the params hash?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you try to achieve and add some code to make it easier to understand your problem? To answer your last question ActiveRecord callbacks do not have access to params which are only available in the controller and view. When you need them in a callback then you have to pass them to the model.

Comment: Do you mean model callbacks? If yes, then they don't have access to `params` and you might want to rethink your approach. A service class that coordinates things tends to be easier to work with than a bunch of callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

There's the 'Dirty' methods: [link](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html). It doesn't check params, as it works on the Database level, not the Controller side, but it's commonly used with callbacks, because callbacks are chained with Database via before_*, after_*.

So what I mean is that maybe you don't need to check anything on the controller's side, but check it via Dirty and callbacks. Dirty provides some very useful methods for your case:

1. You can use '*[attribute]_changed?*'
2. '*will_save_change_to_[attribute]?*'
3. When you need to track from which value to which value the attribute was changed, you need '*[attribute]_change*' that will render the array ['value was', 'value changed to'].

Because you're tracking Boolean value, it might have 2-3 values: True, False, nil. If you have 'null: false' constraint in DB, you will have 2 possible values: True, False, so you might use the 1st or 2nd option. Unfortunately, if you don't have such a 'null: false' contstraint, you need to use 3rd option to check what's the current value. For example, you might compare the new value with '.blank?' to verify that nil will be treated as False.

So what you'll have:

```
before_save :some_callback, if: [attribute]_changed?
# if you need to compare the new_value
before_save :some_callback, if: changed_[attribute]_to_true?

# in private
def changed_[attribute]_to_true?
  return unless [attribute]_changed?

  [attribute]_change.last.present?
end
```

That's just an example, it might not work as expected!